# How to hide columns (G-AZ) when cell value is #N/A

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I currently have a vlookup populating row 1 (cells G1-AZ1) with titles, and would like to  hide the Columns(G1-AZ1) if the vlookup pulls back nothing/#N/A. I know this is a simple macro but I'am new to VBA and I have had zero luck searching the web. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually place such formulas in *ISNA()* and then just use Excel filter to hide empty rows

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,G1:H7,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A3,G1:H7,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: Are you able to use excel to filter by Row?I thought it only filtered by column? I would like the template to auto hide the columns that are not populated by a title. Each column has 50 cells populated below, that I use- if the title is populated.

Comment: When you apply the filter to columns, it shows/hide whole row if filter statement is true(or false  -- it depends on your intentions)(make sure that you have all data cells selected prior you set the filter)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Loop throught he header cells
2. Set the `EntireColumn.Hidden` property based on your criteria
3. Use `.ScreenUpdating = False` to prevent screen flicker and speed it up

---

```
Sub HideColumns()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = [G1:AZ1]
    For Each cl In rng
        If IsError(cl) Then
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = cl = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Else
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = cl = ""
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: To make this even less readable, you could have written `cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = (IsError(cl) And cl = CVErr(xlErrNA)) Or (Not IsError(cl) And cl = CVErr(xlErrNA))` ;-)  +1